# how to get value from array button

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, dom

This is my form code and I would like to know how to get value from array button.

```js
$("#upload_form").submit(function(e) {
    how to get the value of the Submit button I pressed..here ?
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="upload_form" name="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" style="width: 95%">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnUpload1" name="btnUpload" value="1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Upload !</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnUpload2" name="btnUpload" value="2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Upload !</button>
</form>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't get the button in form's submit event handler.

Use button click event handler to get which button is click and save the button's information.

Here is an answer for how to do that:

```js
var submitor = undefined;
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
    submitor = this;
})

$("#upload_form").submit(function(e) {
    var val = $(submitor).val();
    alert(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="upload_form" name="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" style="width: 95%">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnUpload1" name="btnUpload" value="1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Upload !</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnUpload2" name="btnUpload" value="2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Upload !</button>
</form>
```